# Getting Error 403 Forbidden to ajax on https on ec2 instance

Tags: drupal

I have used better exposed filter module and set it as on click submit. it set an ajax request when click on the check box. It is causing problem in HTTPS. it is working fine in HTTP.

An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 403
Debugging information follows.Path: /views/ajax
StatusText: Forbidden
ResponseText: 403 Forbidden
ForbiddenYou don't have permission to access /views/ajaxon this server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of things that you need to check:

```
It is likely you have not set $base_url in your settings.php file.
There is a mode_security file on Amazone EC2 server increase the size of post data when using https. Hope it will work Happy coding...
```